# Can a kraken cast wizard spells which require verbal and somatic components?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, spellcasting, spell-components

The Kraken, according to the monster manual, can "Understand Abyssal, Celestial, Infernal, And Primordial But Can't Speak, Telepathy 120 Ft." The Kraken also does not have hands. It seems as if the Kraken can barely cast any spells at all. Can these factors be somehow overcome or explained away, ideally whilst staying within the basic 5e rules?

Comment: I’ve rolled back the recent edit, we prefer to keep it at one question per question.

Comment: okay, I may try to re-add the edit later in a way that keeps within the one-question rule.

Comment: What kraken, [this one](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/kraken)? Its statblock doesn't have spellcasting at all...

Comment: Where did the idea "Kraken can cast wizard spells" come from?

Comment: this is asking about a kraken that has class levels

Answer (score 6):

#### If you can’t speak, you can’t perform verbal components.

The rules for verbal components say:

> Most spells require the chanting of mystic words. The words themselves aren't the source of the spell's power; rather, the particular combination of sounds, with specific pitch and resonance, sets the threads of magic in motion. Thus, a character who is gagged or in an area of silence, such as one created by the silence spell, can't cast a spell with a verbal component.

No speaking, no mystical words.

#### The DM can do whatever they want, so make it psionic.

The DM can make monster’s do whatever they want to, and don’t even have to justify it with logic, especially for something like a boss monster. *Just give it innate Spellcasting*:

> A monster with the innate ability to cast spells has the Innate Spellcasting special trait. Unless noted otherwise, an innate spell of 1st level or higher is always cast at its lowest possible level and can’t be cast at a higher level. If a monster has a cantrip where its level matters and no level is given, use the monster’s challenge rating.

Monsters with innate Spellcasting often have the ability to cast their spells *without* components because they’re inherently magical creatures. Just make you kraken an innate spellcaster (often called psionic).